# How to make a leaderboard command on discord.py using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to write a Discord bot with my friends and I’m trying to make a leaderboard command. I have been trying to fix the command and refilling the numbers, but nothing has worked.

Comment: How is your data on coins stored? Is it a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it’s a dictionary

Comment: Please, show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to sort `dict.items()` because then you'll be stuck finding the keys. You can use a class definition.

```py
class LeaderBoardPosition:

    def __init__(self, user, coins):
        self.user = user
        self.coins = coins
```

and use a simple sorting function (this assuming your data is stored in "coins"):

```py
leaderboards = []
for key, value in coins.items():
    leaderboards.append(LeaderBoardPosition(key, value))

top = sorted(leaderboards, key=lambda x: x.coins, reverse=True)
```

Now you have a list, named `top` with the data. Here is a simple leaderboard function.

```py
await message.channel.send(f'**<< 1 >>** <@{top[0].user}> with {top[0].coins} coins')
try:
    await message.channel.send(f'**<< 2 >>** <@{top[1].user}> with {top[1].coins} coins')
    try:
        await message.channel.send(f'**<< 3 >>** <@{top[2].user}> with {top[2].coins} coins')
    except IndexError:
        await message.channel.send('There is no 3rd place yet.')
except IndexError:
    await message.channel.send('There is no 2nd place yet.')
```

Comment: in the second code where it does the list and sorting, can you explain it more?

Comment: So basically I made a class so it is easier to store both the user identifier and the coins value so I can sort them by attribute (`x.coins`) and the object still has the user id, so then they can be mentioned with `<@123456>` in the message sending part